# In WF4, how do I persist each child activity of a parallel for each loop while keeping them synchronous?

Tags: synchronization, persistence, workflow-foundation-4, parallel.foreach

I have a `ProcessId` activity that takes in an ID, accesses a SQL database, does some work, and returns nothing to the caller. If the SQL database is busy, `ProcessId` runs a delay activity and tries to access the database again upon completing the delay. While `ProcessId` is idle (due to the delay activity), I want it to persist.

I have an array of IDs that I need to process. I have a `Main` activity that has a `ParallelForEach` activity to run `ProcessId` on each ID.

How do I ensure that each `ProcessId` persists correctly and executes synchronously in the `ParallelForEach` activity?

Currently, I have a `Host` activity. When it executes, it has a `WorkflowApplication` that is assigned an `InstanceStore`. This `WorkflowApplication` invokes `ProcessId`. In `Main`'s `ParallelForEach` activity, I call the `Host` activity. However, this doesn't seem to work. Either nothing is persisted or the activities are executed one after the other.

Comment: PFEs run synchronously, only switching activities in mid execution if they go idle.  Do you have any activities that actually go idle?  Does your activity create a bookmark?  Can't go idle unless you do that.

Comment: I have a `Delay` activity inside of the `ProcessId` activity. When I schedule the `Delay` activity, I also add a callback method. I thought that took care of returning from the Delay activity as well as going idle.

Comment: Uh, the only Delay activity is part of WF3, not WF4.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.delayactivity.aspx Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about this Delay class that derives from NativeActivity: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.delay.aspx

Comment: Aaah, missed that.  That activity will induce idle.  Next question, when you configure the workflow application, do you pass a func to [PersistableIdle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.persistableidle.aspx)?  You have to do this and return `PersistableIdleAction.Unload` to instruct the workflow to suspend execution and persist itself.

Comment: Yes, I did that. So I followed [Microsoft's tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773.aspx). So right now, my `Main` activity creates many `Host` activities. In the `Execution` method of these `Host` activities, a `WorkflowApplication` that is configured to persist in the way that's described in the tutorial. Does it matter that creating a `WorkflowApplication` is created during the execution of an activity? If that is not allowed, what would be an alternative?

Comment: Huh?  You're creating workflow applications in a workflow?  Creating activities during execution of the workflow?

Comment: Yes. So I'm guessing that is not allowed. I want to be able to use the PFE activity to call multiple `ProcessId` activities. How can I persist those individual activities? Right now, if I persist the `Main` activity, then it doesn't persist each individual `ProcessId` activity.

Comment: You're doing weird stuff outside the bounds of normal workflow here.  I guess you're creating child workflows because you found out you couldn't schedule activities that were not "declared" to the runtime during `CacheMetadata`?  Yeah, your design is flawed from the getgo.  You can't just add activities while it runs, you have to construct your complete activity tree prior to execution.